# Latex command line line length

Tags: command-line, latex, pdflatex

When running latex, the command-line output it cut after 80 characters:

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig:assign-by-x' on page 76 undefined on input line 2
41.
```

Any idea how I can stop this?

Version is:

```
pdfTeX using libpoppler 3.141592-1.40.3-2.2 (Web2C 7.5.6)
kpathsea version 3.5.6
```

on Ubuntu Linux 9.04, bash shell.

Comment: I don't know if this is actually relevant or not, but what command shell are you running this in?  tcsh?  bash?  Windows shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The settings for this, along with all other setting for latex, are in `/etc/texmf/texmf.cnf` (on Ubuntu anyway). The setting for line length is:

```
max_print_line=79
```

We don't want to change this file, but all of the settings are configurable via environmental settings. So we can override this simply by running latex using:

```
max_print_line=120 latex myfile
```

Note that this breaks some things - I notice vim errorformat stops working properly.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration setting to fix this was given in 2013 in @ulrikefischer comment to @tacohoekwater [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4055/48816).

Today, for the case of `XeLaTeX` provided by `MiKTeX v20.6.29`

```
PS> initexmf --edit-config-file xelatex
```

opens `Notepad` on `$AppData\MiKTeX\miktex\config\xelatex.ini` in which you can put the line

```
max_print_line=N
```

where `N` is your desired output line length.

Answer (score 0):

As best I can tell from looking at documentation and doing some experiments, this is a hardwired cutoff that can't be changed.  The MikTeX pdfTeX documentation (http://docs.miktex.org/2.6/manual/pdftex.html) gives some commands for changing error widths, but they do nothing on Ubuntu.  The "pdftex --help" output gives nothing useful at all.

Sorry.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I found too.

Answer (score 0):

I'am using MacTeX / TeX Live. Setting max_line_print:

> max_print_line = 2048

in texmf.cnf, which is on Mac OS X located in:

> /usr/local/texlive/2009/texmf.cnf

works fine ... for me.