# Very long file names in vim errorformats

Tags: vim, latex, pdflatex, errorformat

I've been working on an errorformat for LaTeX with the LaTeXBox plugin for vim, and I have recognized a problem that I am not able to solve.

LaTeX produces relatively structured log files, where a Lisp-like paranthesis syntax is used for the parsed files, e.g.:

```
(/path/to/some/file.xxx ...)
```

At first, this looks like a simple problem, and we can use the `%P/%O/%Q` directives with `%r` and `%f` to parse the file names. For simple `.tex` files and projects, this works well. However, in some cases the lines may break before the file name is finished. For instance, we may get something like this:

```
) (/some/file/with/long/file/name.sty) (/some/file/with/even/longer/fi
le/name.sty (...
))
```

Most of the above output can be parsed correctly, however, as shown above, one of the paths have been broken and will not be parsed. It is enough with one such error to break the stack of files, which leads to erroneous parsing of the log file.

The problem can be stated in a more general way: I want to use the errorformat to parse file names that break across lines:

```
/path/to/some/
file.txt
```

I am looking for a solution to this problem, either with some more vim magic (perhaps I have missed a nice errorformat option?), or perhaps with some options for `latex` or `pdflatex`. Any solution is appreciated.

Comment: I think this is impossible to handle inside Vim; the Tex toolchain shouldn't insert hard line breaks in the middle of its output; that's just weird!

Comment: @IngoKarkat: That's my conclusion as well. I am currently looking for a way to make the Tex toolchain make more sane log files...

Comment: If all else fails, you could append a filter (e.g. with `sed`) to the `'makeprg'` that is used for the build. But that's ugly, problematic on Windows (different, inferior tools), and therefore a last resort.

Comment: @glts: It's annoying, because the latex log file is really very well structured. The line breaks are the only thing causing a problem, I think.

@IngoKarkat: Yes, I have been considering that. The problem is to make a good `sed` script (or similar). It has to match broken file paths, and only match actual paths.

Comment: [This link can be helpful if you intend to remove the line breaks.](http://tekonomist.wordpress.com/2011/04/18/latex-plugin-update-new-build-command-and-parsing-tex-log-files/)

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found a good solution to this. Apperantly, one may use `max_print_line=<number>` to set the wrap with of the latex log output. Thus, if one issues the latex command:

```
max_print_line=2000 pdflatex <filename>.tex
```

The problem with filenames being broken across lines will probably be solved, since lines will not be broken until they reach 2000 colums.

I found this solution first through [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1294063/51634).

So, to sum up: I think the `%P/%O/%Q` directives with `%r` and `%f` to parse the file names should work if one uses `max_print_line`.

Beware: this is max_print_line, not max_print_lines.